# Running multiple ssh commands

Tags: command-line, ssh, git

I've got a command in bitbucket that runs multiple ssh commands, is there a way to run each command once the previous has completed?

```
ssh <user>@<host> 'cd /<dir>/example.com; git clone https://<user>:<password>@bitbucket.org/<bucket>/examplegit.git -b develop; mv examplegit/* mv examplegit/.* .; rmdir examplegit;'
```

```
Cloning into 'examplegit'...
mv: cannot stat 'mv': No such file or directory
mv: cannot move 'examplegit/.' to './.': Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move 'examplegit/..' to './..': Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move 'examplegit/.git' to './.git': Directory not empty
rmdir: failed to remove 'examplegit': Directory not empty
```

I can run the same command multiple times and get a different amount and order of errors. Which makes sense, they are all being executed straight away but not always ready to be executed.

Being able to run one after the other would solve all this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to run each command once the previous has completed?

That's literally how it already works.

If you had been using `&` as the separator, *that* would allow commands to run simultaneously, but the `;` separator **always waits** for the previous command to exit.

> I can run the same command multiple times and get a different amount and order of errors.

The problem is that you're missing half of your command. Specifically, this part:

```
mv examplegit/* mv examplegit/.* .;
```

should probably be:

```
mv examplegit/* .; mv examplegit/.* .;
```

Because the 'mv' fails halfway and leaves a non-empty directory, it makes sense that the following 'rmdir' fails and a subsequent 'git clone' also refuses to clone into that non-empty directory.

Overall, you should also consider replacing all `;` with `&&` (**two** &'s) which additionally checks the exit code of the previous command, and will stop if the previous command failed.

```
ssh <user>@<host> 'cd /<dir>/example.com &&
    git clone https://<user>:<password>@bitbucket.org/<bucket>/examplegit.git -b develop &&
    mv examplegit/* . &&
    mv examplegit/.* . &&
    rmdir examplegit'
```

And, consider switching entirely to [a different git deployment method](https://gitolite.com/deploy.html) that doesn't involve making a fresh clone.

(Your current method also leaves the entire Git repository accessible to all your visitors – they probably can just `git clone https://example.com/.git` and download all of your private source code.)

For example:

1. Clone your repo to `~/git/example.com` *once*
2. To deploy, run:

   ```
   ssh user@host 'cd ~/git/example.com &&
                  git pull --ff-only &&
                  GIT_WORK_TREE=/<dir>/example.com git checkout -f'
   ```

The methods in the linked article will also take care of renamed/deleted files, while yours will keep old files forever.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I found a more elegant solution anyway, I'm not sure how I overlooked it. https://<user>:<password>@bitbucket.org/<bucket>/examplegit.git -b develop /home/webroot/examplegit;